# Unable to access my .net website from internet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am new to networking and routing.

I have hosted my website (enabled https) in azure vm having firewall settings. Have opened the ports for the websites.

But still unable to access my website from internet.

I have 2 sites running. the main website which is running on port 443. To access this site , it is directed to openid oauth2 identity site running on port 44300. Both the ports are opened. The site is running perfect when i access from the hosted server and also other servers.

I am trying to access this main site from my home internet. It is not working.I want to access this site from internet as well.

additional info:

Main website hosted in server which is connected to internet with a Connection which has got a IPv4 Default Gateway - eg; A

My own pc connected to internet with a different connection with different IPv4 Default Gateway.

With this above setup, it is possible to achieve my requirement?

Can anyone help what has to be done to access my website from outside world?

Thanks

Comment: Based on the little info you have posted you will probably only get suggestions to try. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Can you also add details about the NSG's configured for your VM?